# How can I reference a composite PK as a foreign key in another table and still have a normalized database?

Tags: sql, create-table, erd

First off, here's my code for the three tables I'm having problems with:

```
    CREATE TABLE ProgramSupervisor
    (    EmpNo                                CHAR (6),
         ProgramSupervisorNo                  CHAR (6),
         TeamNo                               CHAR (3),
         CONSTRAINT PKProgramSupervisor PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo , ProgramSupervisorNo) ,
         CONSTRAINT FKProgSupEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee  )
```

Another:

```
    CREATE TABLE ISL
    (    ISLNo                                  CHAR (6) ,
         EmpNo                                  CHAR(6),
         ProgramSupervisorNo                    CHAR (6),
         ISLName                                VARCHAR (30),
         ISLStreet                              VARCHAR (40),
         ISLCity                                VARCHAR (30),
         ISLState                               CHAR (2),
         ISLZip                                 CHAR (5),
    CONSTRAINT PKISL PRIMARY KEY (ISLNo) ,
    CONSTRAINT FKISLProgSupNo FOREIGN KEY (ProgramSupervisorNo, EmpNo) 
               REFERENCES ProgramSupervisor  )
```

And another:

```
    CREATE TABLE Hourly
    (    EmpNo                           CHAR (6),
         ISLNo                           CHAR (3),
          NumberOfWriteUpes              SMALLINT,
    CONSTRAINT PKHourly PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
    CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee,
    CONSTRAINT FKISLNo FOREIGN KEY (ISLNo) REFERENCES ISL  )
```

Here's the ERD and the relationships I'm striving for:

[image]

Now that you have the info, let me explain the problem I'm having. First off, the ERD is a little misleading. I have a ProgramSupervisor table that's a child table of the 'Salary' parent table and 'Salary' is a child table of the parent table 'Employee.' With the PK of 'Employee' being EmpNo, the PK of Salary and then ProgramSupervisor are also EmpNo. However, I also want ProgramSupervisorNo to be a PK of the 'ProgramSupervisor' table and have a composite PK for it. When I create the 'ISL' table, in order to reference the composite 'ProgramSupervisor' PK as a FK in the ISL table, Access requires both PK field names. Doesn't this violate normalization standards? Since it requires both EmpNo and ProgramSupervisorNo in the 'ISL' table, doesn't this mean that ProgramSupervisorNo relies on EmpNo and therefore one of the fields shouldn't be included? I'm new to this so please forgive my shoddy explanations.

Also, 'Hourly' employees belong to one ISL and ISL's can have numerous 'Hourly' employees, but the 'Hourly' table is also a child table of Employee and has EmpNo as its primary key. That being said, if I'm required to put EmpNo and ProgramSupervisorNo in my 'ISL' table, how am I to put the ISLNo in my 'Hourly' table?

Clear as mud? Basically, I just to put ProgramSupervisorNo in the 'ISL' table because each ISL has a ProgramSupervisor. Then, I want to put ISLNo in my 'Hourly' table. Please provide some examples and explain to me like I'm five. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it looks like there are missing or overlayed lines in you diagramm, if you can relate, the the names of fields a only used once, your db loks to be ok, even if you "walk" over "salary" you still have emp# as unique thing

Comment: an other point: this ERD looks very "logical" and could prob use some denomlisation

Comment: The overlayed line is just a page break line and I didn't connect the other Hourly to ISL because I already have EmpNo in the ISL table. I included it mainly because I wanted some advice on how to relate Hourly employee to ISL when I already have EmpNo in ISL due to the ProgramSupervisor-ISL relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From academic point of view a `Primary key` must fit all these points:

- unique
- minimal
- all PK-fields are non-null

Foreign keys are references to other table's primary keys. So they must exactly include the fields that the referenced PK has. And this does not violate normalization since the PK must be minimal (from academic point of view).

When you have a primary key with 2 or more columns and you think it is enough to reference its rows with only one column then your PK is not valid because it is not minimal. When it is valid and you need all these columns to fullfill uniqueness then you also need all these column in the foreign key.

DBMS allow you to define non-minimal PKs but that's then the point where you're leaving the academic concepts.

Comment: So would you recommend not to have 'ProgramSupervisorNo' as a primary key and just leave EmpNo as the single PK field?

Comment: I am not sure about your domain. To find a PK you normally have to do 3 steps: First find all column tuples that can uniquely identify the table's rows. Second eliminate all non-minimal tuples from your list. Third choose one of the tuples left as your primary key. So when `EmpNo` uniquely identifies all rows in `ProgramSupervisorNo` then `(ProgramSupervisorNo, EmpNo)` must be eliminated in step 2 and is not a valid PK-candidate. But I cannot say if that is the case, because I do not know your domain.

Comment: Interesting. I guess EmpNo would be enough to uniquely define ProgramSupervisor rows. They would still need the ProgramSupervisorNo though but maybe that would be a unique key and not a PK? Also, if EmpNo is enough to identify then EmpNo would appear in ISL when I reference it. How would that work with EmpNo being a PK of Hourly when I want to reference ISLNo in the Hourly table? Thanks for the explanations BTW

Comment: Wait, one question: Are there ever two or more rows in `ProgramSupervisor` with the same `EmpNo`?

Comment: No there is not. Each Program Supervisor has its own EmpNo.

Comment: Then `EmpNo` is a very good PK-candidate and every other tuple including `EmpNo` is not even a valid candidate since all these tuples would not be minimal, because `EmpNo` alone is still enough to uniquely identify all rows.

Comment: Okay. Since ProgramSupervisor is a child table of Employee it must have EmpNo as its PK. I'm still confused on the whole ISL and Hourly issue though. I need ISLno as a FK in Hourly...how can I do that if EmpNo is the Hourly PK and EmpNo is already referenced in ISL from the ProgramSupervisor table?

Comment: 1.) When you need ISLno as FK in Hourly then add a column to it and define the FK on this column referencing ISL's PK. 2.) If you need it the other way around, then add another empno column in ISL `hourly_empno` and define the FK there. You should always name the columns of FKs with a concatenation of referenced table and the referenced column name.

Comment: `ISL` has then `programsupervisor_empno` and `hourly_empno` columns. Each of them are FK to an `empno` column of different tables and may contain different empnos in an ISL row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40921/discussion-between-fabian-barney-and-benign-baboon)